# What is the power given by centripetal force?(in circular motion)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, vectors, power, centripetal-force

[image: figure]

> A particle of mass $m$ is moving in a circular path of constant radius
>   such that the centripetal acceleration is varying with time as $a_c =
>  k^2rt^2$ where $k$ is constant. The power given to the particle by the
>   force acting on it is?

## MY ATTEMPT:

Since force and velocity are radial power must be zero, but the answer is not zero . If I find instantaneous power then I am getting $P_i = 2 \pi m k^2 r^2 t$.

Where $P_i$ = instantaneous power,

The answer given is option (b), as in the following figure, but why?

Comment: Why are you thinking that force and velocity are radial?

Comment: @BowlOfRed      Since it is given that the force is centripetal and the radius is constant so the force must be tangential to velocity.

Comment: The force is not described directly in the problem.  If it were purely radial, either the energy could not change (or the radius must change).  Instead, the force must have some non-radial component.  The centripetal acceleration is described, but there is also transverse acceleration.

Comment: @BowlOfRed     How can I find out transverse acceleration from the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean "the force is radial and the velocity is transversal". The power is the change of kinetic energy per time, dE/dt where E=m*v²/2. So it must be

$$P_i = m\cdot k^2\cdot r^2\cdot t$$

The factor $\pi$ or $2\pi$ is not nescessary since that would be a half circle while what you need is a radian and that is $1$ in natural units.

Comment: Since it is given that the force is centripetal and the radius is constant so the force must be tangential to velocity.Please explain the answer clearly. Please.

Comment: The problem does not say the force is centripetal.  Only that there is some force and some component of the resulting acceleration is centripetal.

Comment: @BowlOfRed     But the problem says that acceleration is centripetal!

Comment: @JM97, that's not the way I read it.  The problem says that the centripetal component of acceleration is something particular.  It does not say that the transverse component is zero.  It is simply not described.

Comment: @BowlOfRed      Then how should I find it? Please answer soon? Please.

Comment: @JM97 You don't need to know the exact acceleration.  Use a_c = v^2/r to find an equation for the velocity.  Then you can turn it into energy and power as in the above answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37552/discussion-between-jm97-and-bowlofred).

Answer (score 1):

The particle is moving on a circle, but with variable velocity. So it s a non-uniform circular motion. You see this immediately because the centripetal acceleration is not constant. This means that there is some power given/taken to the particle.

The text gives you the component of the acceleration along the radius of curvature (centripetal acceleration), but it does not say that the tangential acceleration is 0. In fact, it cannot be 0: there must be a tangential acceleration which increases the speed of the particle.

Anyway:

from $r.r = const$ (circular motion)

derive once and get $2 v.r= 0$, so $v$ is orthogonal to $r$ (as we concluded before).

Derive a second time $ v.r= 0$ and get $a.r+v.v=0$.

The first term is minus the centripetal acceleration (which is $-a.n_r$) times the length of $r$, so is $-k^2r^2t^2$ ($r$ is pointing outward, the centripetal acceleration must point toward $-r$ ie. inward and $n_r$ is a unit radial vector).

So you have $-k^2r^2t^2+v.v=0$. Multiply by $1/2m$ and derive again and note that the second term is the derivative of the kinetic energy, ie. power received

$$d/dt(-1/2mk^2r^2t^2+1/2mv.v)=0$$

$$-mk^2r^2t+P=0$$

and you get answer b correctly